# All Post Wordpress Page Error

Tags: plugins, posts, 404-error

I set up the number of elements per page in the Wordpress "Post" page in 999 (max) because i have more than 4k post but since i did that every time I want to go to the page and see my post i'm redirected to a 404 page.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try and reset your permalinks. Go to Settings > Permalinks and hit Save Changes. Clear your cache and then try and visit a post again. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Hi Sam. I already try that but it did not work.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you have an issue with your rewrite rules. Can you check to see if your .htaccess file looks correct? See here: https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess